# How to force python versions to sync in a datalab instance spun from a GCP dataproc cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I've created a Dataproc cluster in GCP using image 1.2. I want to run Spark from a Datalab notebook. This works fine if I keep the Datalab notebook running Python 2.7 as its kernel, but if I want to use Python 3 I run into a minor version mismatch. I demonstrate the mismatch with a Datalab script below:

```py
### Configuration
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/panera/lib')
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = '/opt/conda/bin/python'
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = '/opt/conda/bin/python'

import google.datalab.storage as storage
from io import BytesIO

spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .enableHiveSupport() \
  .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition","true") \
  .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode","nonstrict") \
  .config("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs","false") \
  .getOrCreate() \

sc = spark.sparkContext

### import libraries
from pyspark.mllib.tree import DecisionTree, DecisionTreeModel
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

### trivial example
data = [ 
  LabeledPoint(0.0, [0.0]),
  LabeledPoint(1.0, [1.0]),
  LabeledPoint(1.0, [2.0]),
  LabeledPoint(1.0, [3.0])
]

toyModel = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(sc.parallelize(data), 2, {})
print(toyModel)
```

The error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, pan-bdaas-prod-jrl6-w-3.c.big-data-prod.internal, executor 6): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 124, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.6 than that in driver 3.5, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

Other initialization scripts:
gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/cloud-sql-proxy/cloud-sql-proxy.sh
gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/datalab/datalab.sh
...and scripts that load some of our necessary libraries and utilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python 3 kernel in Datalab is using Python 3.5 rather than Python 3.6

You could try to set up a 3.6 environment inside of Datalab and then install a new kernelspec for it, but it is probably easier to just configure the Dataproc cluster to use Python 3.5

The instructions for setting up your cluster to use 3.5 are [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/datalab#python-3)

Comment: So this is interesting. This technically solves the problem by generating a dataproc cluster with both worker and driver nodes using python 3.5. However numpy is now no longer installed, and my other initialization scripts are incompatible. This answer will very likely get the vote ... but I want to try to figure out the next steps for a day before I close this question.

Comment: Are you using other init actions from the Dataproc github repo, or custom ones? Any idea whether the incompatibilities are related to fundamental differences between 3.5 and 3.6, or if they're just issues with hard-coded version assumptions?

Comment: @DennisHuo, yes, we are using other init actions, but none of these are specific to a python version so far as I can tell. I'll route the numpy issue to a data engineer on our side who would know better if something within the utility is causing the issue.